# I am trying to make a program to remind me when i need to do something but i just cant get it to work

Tags: visual-studio

I don't know what im doing wrong...
If someone could help me that would be awesome, i've been at this for the past 3 hours and cant find any solution (newbie alert)

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SAPI
    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    SAPI.Speak("I will remind you at " & TextBox2.Text & TextBox1.Text)
    'Me.Visible = False




End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim SAPI
    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    If TimeOfDay = TextBox2.Text Then SAPI.Speak(TextBox1.Text)




End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is your expected result?

Comment: Well it vrashes for one and for some reason when the time i picked comes up it doesnt do anything